# jax-ws: unsupported Media Exception content-type from server side

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

my soap client is making successful request and getting 200 OK from soap server. However, the application is erroring due to missing content-type header. I tried to add content-type header in handler but that is not even invoked (using debugger, I can see that method is never hit for inbound message but for outbound it is hit)

Here is the handler code:

```
public class ClientHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
        public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
            if ((Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY)) {
                    System.out.println(" here: in outbound call");
            }


                if (!(Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY)) {
                    Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>)context.get(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS);

                    List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();
                    value.add("text/xml");

                    if (headers != null) {
                        headers.put("content-type", value);
                    } else {
                        Map<String, List<String>> brandNewHeaders = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
                        brandNewHeaders.put("content-type", value);
                        context.put(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS, brandNewHeaders);
                    }
                }

            return true;

        }
```

Here is how I attach my handler

```
WSGService service = new WSGService();
        appPort =  service.getWSGHttpPort();
        final Binding binding = ((BindingProvider) provisionPort).getBinding();
        BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)provisionPort;
        bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, provisionurl);
        List<Handler> handlerList = new ArrayList<>();
        handlerList.add(new ClientHandler());
        binding.setHandlerChain(handlerList);
```

Here is the log I get back for a successful call. NOTE empty content-type on response header, which is causing this error.

```
---[HTTP request - https://foobar/url]---
Accept: [text/xml, multipart/related]
Content-Type: [text/xml; charset=utf-8]
SOAPAction: ["/FOOBARWSG"]
User-Agent: [JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01]
<?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body>**BODY**</S:Body></S:Envelope>--------------------
---[HTTP response - https://foobar/url - 200]---
null: [HTTP/1.0 200 OK]
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: [Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Content-Encoding, X-Client-UID, Authorization, X-Associated-Id]
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: [GET, POST, PUT, DELETE]
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [*]
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: [WWW-Authenticate]
Connection: [close]
Content-Length: [2915]
content-type: []
Date: [Tue, 31 Jan 2017 06:24:05 GMT]
Server: [JBOSS Application Server]
X-WsgSource: [DUMMY,15,2017-01-31 06:24:05]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>--------------------
22:24:07,605 ERROR ErrorPageFilter:180 - Forwarding to error page from request [/dummy/customerType/null] due to exception [Unsupported Content-Type:  Supported ones are: [text/xml]]
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type:  Supported ones are: [text/xml]
```

**EDIT**:

with more debugging, I was able to manually change content-type to include "text/xml" in response through intellij debug console and everything behaved as expected

I changed contentType below to "text/xml" which had empty value in it in  the HttpTrasportPipe.class

```
this.checkStatusCode(responseStream, con);
        Packet reply = request.createClientResponse((Message)null);
        reply.wasTransportSecure = con.isSecure();
        if(responseStream != null) {
            String contentType = con.getContentType();
            if(contentType != null && contentType.contains("text/html") && this.binding instanceof SOAPBinding) {
                throw new ClientTransportException(ClientMessages.localizableHTTP_STATUS_CODE(Integer.valueOf(con.statusCode), con.statusMessage));
            }

            this.codec.decode(responseStream, contentType, reply);
        }
```

Comment: perhaps I'm mistaken, but the request from your client seems valid, the problem is the response from the server, which does not have content -type and it contains invalid SOAP XML (see missing soap header tags, and body start tag). The error is not in the client then, it's on the server.

Comment: yes, it is on server side which I am aware of. I am trying to add content-type header to response object I get back from server. but before my handler, exception is thrown

Comment: ooh, so you're kinda trying to _fix_ incoming invalid soap? having to communicate through SOAP is troublesome itself, having to do magic like yours is *deep*! Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.TransportTubeFactory` to access the `Codec.decode` call in `HttpTransportPipe`; see the last part of my answer on this question: [UnsupportedMediaException -> how do you get the actual response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446318/unsupportedmediaexception-how-do-you-get-the-actual-response/)

In that question we were more interested in the body of the 'faulty' response, but you can use the Codec wrapper just as easily to overrule the `Content-Type`:

Snippet from my CodecWrapper:

```
    @Override
    public void decode(InputStream in, String contentType, Packet response) throws IOException {
        // TODO: here you can access / change any of the parameters before sending it to the actual SOAP Codec
        wrapped.decode(in, contentType, response);
    }
```

Some remarks:

- i've written the referenced answer for jaxws-rt, and according to your error message you're using the JRE internal version. It should work the same though. The only difference is the package names.
- you're lucky the content-type is null, otherwise you would get a `ClientTransportException` that is much harder to circumvent (without copying a lot of code from HttpTransportPipe)
- if you can find an easier way to proxy your HTTP traffic and re-write the Content-Type that way, that would be neater. See for example the accepted answer here: [SOAP unsupported media exception text/plain Supported ones are: [text/xml]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64866031/soap-unsupported-media-exception-text-plain-supported-ones-are-text-xml) on how to use Apache httpd as a reverse proxy