# SOAP unsupported media exception text/plain Supported ones are: [text/xml]

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-ws, content-type

In our app we have the following line of code which makes a SOAP request to a service

```
@WebResult(
      name = "GetRequestResponse",
      targetNamespace = "urn://x-artefacts-smev-gov-ru/services/message-exchange/types/1.1",
      partName = "parameters"
   )
   GetRequestResponse getRequest(@WebParam(name = "GetRequestRequest",targetNamespace = "urn://x-artefacts-smev-gov-ru/services/message-exchange/types/1.1",partName = "parameters") GetRequestRequest var1) throws InvalidContentException, SMEVFailureException, SenderIsNotRegisteredException, SignatureVerificationFaultException, UnknownMessageTypeException;
```

It used to work until the service changed its response content type from `text/xml` to `text/plain`

It still returns valid XML but just in `text/plain`

I don't want to drastically modify the code since it's a very old and outdated legacy library used speciafically to make requests to the service (also, I am not sure whether there's something which could replace it)

To summarize we get the following exception:

```
ru.voskhod.smev.message_exchange_service_client.WebServiceClientException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]
  at ru.voskhod.smev.message_exchange_service_client.MessageExchangeEndpoint.getRequest(MessageExchangeEndpoint.java:457)
```

Is there a way to make it accept `text/plain` and treat it just like `text/xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an **intermediate reverse proxy** (e.g. locally where the client runs) that **overwrites** `text/xml` with `text/plain` on the `Content-Type` **response header**, and then talk to that proxy instead of talking to the server.

e.g. you can use [httpd](http://httpd.apache.org/) with with `ProxyPass`/`ProxyPassReverse` directives (from [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) module)
combined with `Header set Content-Type "text/plain"` (from [mod_headers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) module).

If the client cannot be configured to call a new domain(e.g. localhost), you may need to add a `hosts` file entry to resolve the remote server's domain to the reverse proxy's bind address. But the reverse proxy will still need to be able to dns-resolve the original address of the remote server, so for this to work at least one of the two(the client or the reverse proxy) may need to be [containerized](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container/#:%7E:text=A%20Docker%20container%20image%20is,tools%2C%20system%20libraries%20and%20settings.).

Answer (score 0):

Change the calling http request header. The 'content-type' header should be 'text/xml'.