# Modifying standard JAX-WS application client to make it accept text/plain as text/xml

Tags: java, xml, soap, jax-ws

In our project we have the following jax-ws application client (there are many more methods so I just added the one we're having issues with):

```
@WebService(
   name = "SMEVMessageExchangePortType",
   targetNamespace = "urn://x-artefacts-smev-gov-ru/services/message-exchange/1.1"
)
@SOAPBinding(
   parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.BARE
)
public interface SMEVMessageExchangePortType {

   @WebResult(
      name = "GetRequestResponse",
      targetNamespace = "urn://x-artefacts-smev-gov-ru/services/message-exchange/types/1.1",
      partName = "parameters"
   )
   @Produces
   GetRequestResponse getRequest(@WebParam(name = "GetRequestRequest",targetNamespace = "urn://x-artefacts-smev-gov-ru/services/message-exchange/types/1.1",partName = "parameters") GetRequestRequest var1) throws InvalidContentException, SMEVFailureException, SenderIsNotRegisteredException, SignatureVerificationFaultException, UnknownMessageTypeException;

}
```

It worked fine untill recently we started getting responses as `text/plain` not as `text/xml`

It led to the following exception:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]
```

My question is whether it's possible to modify the code to treat any given `text/plain` response as `text/xml`

Ideally to have something similar to `@Produces` and `@Consumes` just like in JAX-RS

If not, maybe we could use a third-party SOAP library which implements that behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're not getting `text/html` as a response, you can use my answer on this question to rewrite the content type:
[jax-ws: unsupported Media Exception content-type from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951193/jax-ws-unsupported-media-exception-content-type-from-server-side/)

Or if possible you could use a reverse proxy as described here: [SOAP unsupported media exception text/plain Supported ones are: [text/xml]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64866031/soap-unsupported-media-exception-text-plain-supported-ones-are-text-xml)